# Scala compiler and JVM disagree about version of Akka is loaded

Tags: scala, constructor, akka

**Edit:** To clarify, it is as though the compiler and runtime disagree about which version of Akka is on the classpath.  In addition to this situation, in which the compiler sees new methods but the runtime raises `NoSuchMethodError`, I get the same sort of error when I later try to call `ActorContext.children` (the compiler sees it but the JVM raises `NoSuchMethod`).  This problem might be more general than Akka.

I've done `mvn clean` and checked my Scala REPL version many times.

**Original question:**

The [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html) and [API](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.1/#akka.actor.Props) for version 2.2.1 (the version I'm using) says that Actors with constructor arguments should be built like this:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

class MyActor(one: Int, two: Double, three: String) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "test" => println("%d %g %s".format(one, two, three))
  }
}

val system = ActorSystem("MyActorSystem")
val actor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor], 1, 2.0, "three"))
```

Although this compiles, it raises a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.Props$.apply(Ljava/lang/Class;Lscala/collection/Seq;)Lakka/actor/Props;` exception when you try to run it.

Running it on the REPL results in

```
<console>:12 error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[MyActor](classOf[$MyActor])
 required: () => akka.actor.Actor
       val actor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor], 1, 2.0, "three"))
                                               ^
```

If I take the REPL's suggested change,

```
val actor = system.actorOf(Props(() => new MyActor(1, 2.0, "three")))
```

it works without comment on the REPL and with a

```
[warn] test.scala:10 method apply in object Props is deprecated: use Props.withDispatcher and friends
    val actor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor], 1, 2.0, "three"))
                               ^
```

warning in the compiler.  The documentation and [Migration Guide (2.1.x to 2.2.x)](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0-RC1/project/migration-guide-2.1.x-2.2.x.html) both affirm this deprecation, saying that the closure technique (the one I'm using) results in non-serializable Actors.

I don't want to use something deprecated, especially since I'm just starting work with this library.  I don't understand the comment about `Props.withDispatcher` and friends, since I just want to use the default dispatcher, at least for now.  Are there any examples of this working?

**Edit:** My pom.xml is shown below.  I've commented out all of the tests because there's no version of `scalatest` that works with Scala 2.10.2.  I've cleaned the `target` directory many times: there's no hint of other Scala versions anywhere (and there never has been any other versions of Akka).

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>plotsmanship</name>
  <!-- <description>TODO</description> -->
  <inceptionYear>2013</inceptionYear>

  <groupId>org.plotsmanship</groupId>
  <artifactId>plotsmanship</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
    <scala.version>2.10.2</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Real dependencies for the jar -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
      <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
      <version>1.7R4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-testkit_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencies for testing only (resolves to junit-4.11.jar hamcrest-core-1.3.jar scalatest_2.10-2.0.M6-SNAP8.jar) -->
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!--   <groupId>junit</groupId> -->
    <!--   <artifactId>junit</artifactId> -->
    <!--   <version>4.11</version> -->
    <!--   <scope>test</scope> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!--   <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId> -->
    <!--   <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId> -->
    <!--   <version>2.0.M6-SNAP8</version> -->
    <!--   <scope>test</scope> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <!-- <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory> -->
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <!-- <goal>testCompile</goal> -->
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <args>
                <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                <arg>-feature</arg>
                <!-- <arg>-make:transitive</arg>   (is an unsupported option) -->
                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
              </args>
              <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
              <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- <plugin> -->
      <!--   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
      <!--   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> -->
      <!--   <version>2.13</version> -->
      <!--   <configuration> -->
      <!--     <useFile>false</useFile> -->
      <!--     <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport> -->
      <!--     <includes> -->
      <!--       <include>**/*Test.*</include> -->
      <!--       <include>**/*Suite.*</include> -->
      <!--     </includes> -->
      <!--   </configuration> -->
      <!-- </plugin> -->

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.plotsmanship.Main</mainClass>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>./lib</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                target/lib
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use akka 2.2.x and scala 2.10.y you may have a problem: look into scala/lib directory, you will see akka-actors.jar there, this is 2.1.z version of akka (just look inside in MANIFEST or some typical classes). So if you run your app like this:

```
scala -cp $YourLibs:akka-actors-2.2.x ...
```

2.1 jar of akka will be added first (automatically) and will not be overrided by 2.2 from your classpath.

**Workaround:**

run it manually without scala wrapper:

```
java -cp $ScalaHome/lib/scala-library.jar:$AkkaHome/$Akka_2.2_jars YourMainClass
```

P.S. I do not understand why akka jar is shipped with scala

Comment: Indeed: that's exactly it.  To test it, I temporarily moved akka-actors.jar out of $SCALA_HOME/lib and ran my test on the Scala REPL.  It worked perfectly.  The conclusion, I think, is that Scala 2.10.2 is incompatible with Akka 2.2.x if you intend to work from the REPL.

Comment: This gives us even simpler workaround: remove that akka-actor.jar from scala/lib :)

Comment: True, but I can't expect users of my package to do that, while I would like them to be able to use the REPL, so I just downgraded my dependency to Akka 2.1.4.  The reason Scala is bundling Akka is because they want to absorb it into the standard library, a reasonable goal, but it introduced a hard-to-debug error.

Comment: I have posted a question to akka mail list:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/hC2Fn4d6TZc

Answer (score 1):

Try to take a look at the libraries in your classpath. Even when you specify a classpath running scala -cp, scala automatically adds the scala standard library and other libraries in the lib directory of your scala home. Please check [here](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SIW/Classpath).

Try writing a piece of code in your main to print the classpath. It will help you find what is being loaded. This [one](http://snipplr.com/view/16079/) is in java, but it can help.

I copied and pasted your first example, just like specified in the API and built it with this build.sbt:

```
name := "My Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
libraryDependencies ++= {
    Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.1",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.2.1",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.2.1"
    )
}
```

and it worked like a charm:

```
$ sbt clean compile run
[info] Loading global plugins from ~/.sbt/plugins
...........
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Sep 13, 2013 6:03:05 PM
[info] Running MyActor 
1 2.00000 three
```

Comment: No, even if I include these libraries, my example behaves the same way.  (E.g. from the REPL as `scala -cp akka-actor_2.10-2.2.1.jar:akka-testkit_2.10-2.2.1.jar:akka-remote_2.10-2.2.1.jar` or compiled into a Maven project.)

Comment: I think you have an older version of akka coming first in your classpath. Try using my build.sbt and checking what is being loaded in your classpath. If your pom.xml refers to library that depends on akka 2.1, it will get loaded.

Comment: The only libraries the pom downloads are Akka 2.2.1.  Surely if I load them explicitly on the classpath, as in the example in my previous comment, then I can't get the wrong version.  (I might get *no* Akka loaded if I spelled it wrong, but I wouldn't get the wrong one.)

Comment: I think it might be good in your clarification to give details about your compile and run environment. This is not an akka issue, it is a classpath issue. Providing your pom.xml, scala version and the commands you are using to compile and run will be helpful.

Comment: I'm gradually realizing that, thanks.  Scala version is of course 2.10.2 and the pom (too big for a comment) shouldn't matter in the commandline test described above.  I just finished moving all of this to a `Main` class, ran it with `mvn exec:java` instead of the `scala` commandline and it works.  I'm trying to reformulate my question now; I'm baffled that `scala -cp ...` can be different than `mvn exec:java` with the same libraries--- how it might be confused by jars that aren't even on my disk or in my classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your help: your feedback was very helpful for narrowing down on the real problem.  It was Akka-related, but it was also batch-vs-REPL related, and you suggested that I try to run it as a batch process.  Now I know that the REPL libraries can supplant the ones on the classpath.